# How can I get a list of all possible partitions of a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, combinatorics

Suppose I have an R vector of unique elements such as `x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)`.

Is there a function to give me a list of all possible partitions of this vector `x`? I guess each partition would be a list of vectors, where each element in `x` belongs to one of the vectors. I want all possible partitions into any number of sets of any size.

(I think the number of such partitions is something like `2^n * n!`, where `n` is the number of unique elements. I will probably not be using this function on vectors with more than 4 unique elements.)

Comment: Your estimate seems to be too large.  Call K the number of partitions.  It is obvious that K(1) = 1 and K(2) = 2.  You now have the relation: for N > 2, K(N) = 1 + N * (K(N - 1)).  That is, consider the set of all of the elements, and then each set, with one particular element removed.  This also leads to an algorithm for construction of the partitions.

Comment: The value of K(N) for N>1 would seem to depend on whether order of the partitions and order of the elements within the partitions matter. Would you provide your expected results for N=2 and N=3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a solution that will get you a complete list of partitions, each one of which is represented as a list of vectors. Since a list of lists is pretty ugly when printed to the screen, I've also shown you how to get a more nicely printed object.

```
library(partitions)

x <- c(2,4,6)       # Substitute the vector for which you want partitions 
parts <- listParts(length(x))
out <- rapply(parts, function(ii) x[ii], how="replace")

# This step is for cosmetic purposes only. It allows you to take advantage of
# the `print.equivalence` print method when printing the object to a console 
for(i in seq_along(out)) class(out[[i]]) <- c("list", "equivalence")
out
[[1]]
[1] (2,4,6)

[[2]]
[1] (2,6)(4)

[[3]]
[1] (2,4)(6)

[[4]]
[1] (4,6)(2)

[[5]]
[1] (2)(4)(6)
```

See also `setparts()` in the same package for a more compact way to represent the same set of partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you are looking for,

```
install.packages("gregmisc", dependencies = TRUE)
library(gregmisc)

x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
print(combinations(5,i,x,repeats=TRUE))
}
```